# Making Password Protected Webpages In SharpDox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, documentation, password-protection

I'm using sharpdox to create documentation from my codes/summaries.

Is there anyway to make password-protected web pages in Sharpdox ?

I want to protect some api and documentation web pages for only commercial customers. They should login via password that I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a .htaccess and .htpasswd file in your documentation folder.
Here is a site to create such files:
[.htaccess](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/)
[.htpasswd](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

Drop both files into the root folder of your documentation and try to access it.